# Why is Angular's SimpleChange.previousValue initially undefined?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component with one property decorated with `@Input`. I explicitly initialized that property to a certain value.
The first time the property changes to a new value, the corresponding `SimpleChange.currentValue` does have the correct new value, but `SimpleChange.previousValue` is `undefined`!

The component's code is this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService1Service } from '../test-service-1.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-test',
  templateUrl: './input-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-test.component.css']
})
export class InputTestComponent implements OnChanges {

  constructor(public myTestSrv: TestService1Service) { }

  @Input() prop: string = 'Test 0';
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const chng = changes['prop'];
    this.myTestSrv.addMsg(chng.previousValue + ' → ' + chng.currentValue);
  }
}
```

In the last line, where a message is added to `myTestSrv`, the first change to `prop` causes this message to be added:

```
undefined → Test 1
```

instead of

```
Test 0 → Test 1
```

although I verified that `'Test 0'` was indeed assigned to `prop` before the first change occurred.

I couldn't find any question that addresses the same issue, and although I saw in one or two places (I forgot where exactly) something like "and because it's the first change, `previousValue` is `undefined`", there was no explanation, and it just doesn't make sense.
Being the first change doesn't imply an initial value of `undefined`, and if it has to be `undefined` then (logically) the first change must be from `undefined` to `'Test 0'`, and the second change from `'Test 0'` to `'Test 1'`.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Acording to documentation and source code as well for OnChanges lifecycle hook:

> A lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes

So from my point of view the OnChanges doesn't care that you're initializing your property locally. He know about the changes which cames from the parent. (even if you put an initial value in component, and in the parent as well, the value from the parent will be displayed anyway).

And besides that, even if you provide an initial value from the parent, there's the 'first change' attribute which is set to `true` and the previousValue to `undefined` every time.

If we take a look at the source code we'll see:

```
const isFirstChange = this.unchangedInputs.has(property);
const previousValue = isFirstChange ? undefined : 
      this.getInputValue(property);
```

So, as I said above, the first time, every time `previousValue` will be `undefined` because of `firstChange` which is `true`

Comment: Where does that snippet exist? Can you please provide a link, or a source file path?